# Chineese Chracters (Mandarin ) text Sorting

Tags: ios, sorting

I am trying to sort Mandarin texts using "sortedArrayUsingDescriptors". But it showing me wrong results. After some research I came to know they have two types of sorting: Stroke & Phonetics. Stroke is by number of lines in their characters. Phonetics is by their pronunciation.  Could any one help to sort Mandarin texts by Pronunciation.

Comment: How do you expect the sort method to work with Phonetics Sorting ? Can you give an example ?

Comment: I am looking for a sorting that the iPhone does in the Address book, if the language set is Mandarin.